# Powershell Create Log file exception

Tags: powershell, logging

I currently running a script and where I can see the exceptions in the control panel. 
For example

```
Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot drop the table 'testtabel', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."
At line:383 char:36
+         $insertData.ExecuteNonQuery <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

This is no error in the script so the script moves on but I want to save these exception in a text file. I tried different methods like

```
$_ | Out-File C:\errors.txt -Append
```

or other log functions I had found on the Internet.

Is there just an easy way to extract these exception to a text file?

Comment: `$error` is the automatic variable for errors. So if you want to export the last error it would be `$error[0] | Out-File C:\errors.txt -Append`

Comment: Are you getting the $_ from a try catch...from a pipe?

Answer (score 3):

There are two methods, the `$Error` automatic variable that stores all error objects in it, or `Try{}Catch{}` using the `$PSItem` or `$_` automatic variables.

```
Try {
  .. commands ..
} Catch {
  # Error TYPE
  "[$($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)]" | Out-File C:\Temp\errorlog.txt
  # Error MESSAGE
  $_.Exception.Message | Out-File C:\Temp\errorlog.txt
}
```